# Generate PDF/A with ConTeXt

Tags: context, pdf-a

I'm trying to generate valid PDF/A via ConTeXt, but the verapdf validator is reporting an error.

My input document is

```tex
\setupinteraction
  [title={TITLE},
  author={AUTHOR}]

% attempt to generate PDF/A
\setupbackend
  [format=pdf/a-3a,
   profile={sRGB.icc},
   intent=sRGB IEC61966-2.1]
\setupbackend[export=yes]
\setupstructure[state=start,method=auto]

\starttext

\input knuth

\stoptext
```

Compiling this with `context test.mkiv` and testing with `verapdf test.pdf` leads to the following validation error:

```xml
<validationReport profileName="PDF/A-3A validation profile" statement="PDF file is not compliant with Validation Profile requirements." isCompliant="false">
  <details passedRules="130" failedRules="1" passedChecks="1684" failedChecks="1">
    <rule specification="ISO 19005-3:2012" clause="6.6.2.3" testNumber="7" status="failed" passedChecks="0" failedChecks="1">
      <description>All properties specified in XMP form shall use either the predefined schemas defined in the XMP Specification,
                  ISO 19005-1 or this part of ISO 19005, or any extension schemas that comply with 6.6.2.3.2.</description>
      <object>XMPProperty</object>
      <test>(isPredefinedInXMP2005 == true || isDefinedInMainPackage == true || isDefinedInCurrentPackage == true) &amp;&amp; isValueTypeCorrect == true</test>
      <check status="failed">
        <context>root/document[0]/metadata[0](15 0 obj PDMetadata)/XMPPackage[0]/Properties[2](http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/ - dc:description)</context>
        <errorMessage>An XMP property is either not not pre-defined, is not defined in any extension schema, or has invalid type.</errorMessage>
      </check>
    </rule>
  </details>
</validationReport>
```

Is there a way to avoid this validation error? I've tried to use a different PDF/A flavour like pdf/a-1a:2005, but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Can you please check the log file whether the profiles were found and loaded correctly? ConTeXt tdoesn't throw an error if there is a problem but just announces it in the log.

Comment: The log says `profiles > profile specification 'sRGB IEC61966-2.1' loaded from '/usr/share/texmf/tex/context/colors/icc/context/colorprofiles.xml'`, I guess that's the expected thing? Karl Pettersson helped me to narrow the error down to the `dc:description` entry in the metadata: [removing it](https://twitter.com/KarlPettersso10/status/1488976988303994890) stops veraPDF from complaining. I don't understand the specs well enough, but to me this looks like it might be a problem with veraPDF?

Comment: That might indeed be the case. I also had some issues with unintelligible verification errors from veraPDF in the past. There is also the Preflight tool of Apache PDFbox (https://pdfbox.apache.org/).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about PDFbox!  I've raised an [issue](https://github.com/veraPDF/veraPDF-library/issues/1224) for veraPDF on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an issue with the metadata schema supplied by ConTeXt; an appropriate fix is being [discussed](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2022/105086.html) on the mailing list.

For the time being, the PDF can still be made PDF/A-3A compliant by removing the `dc:description` field, e.g. with the [`pikepdf` library](https://pikepdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/metadata.html#removing-metadata-items).

```python
import pikepdf
import sys
infile = sys.argv[1]
outfile = sys.argv[2]
with pikepdf.open(infile) as pdf:
    with pdf.open_metadata() as meta:
        del meta['dc:description']
    pdf.save(outfile)
```

Use the script as `python3 fix.py input.pdf output.pdf`.